# Extjs 5.0: Not able to add items to Ext.window.MessageBox

Tags: extjs

Issue: Not able to add items(through item config) in Ext.window.MessageBox.

Steps: Create sample Ext.window.MessageBox instance and add any item through item config.Other things are working fine except this item config.
Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/aki&view/editor).

Please help me in this issue if you find any workaround or any fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can add items to [**`Ext.window.MessageBox`**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html) by calling [**`add`**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html#method-add) method.

**Code snippet:**

```
afterrender: function () {
    var mb = Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Record(s) already exists',
        msg: "msg<br/>msg",
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        closable: false
    });
    mb.add({
        xtype: 'textfield',
        emptyText: 'Enter text here'
    });
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jsv)

Comment: Thnx for answer but why does it not work with items config ?

Comment: As you can see in the [class](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/src/MessageBox.js.html) that it itself assigning items in `initComponent` function: `me.items = [me.topContainer, me.progressBar];`

Comment: Also as passed in `show` method `title`, `msg`, `icon`... etc are being used in that class but there is no `items` in it.